# estimating the weather

Tags: python

The estimation is considered correct if estimated as rainy and actual rainfall is greater than 0. also it is correct if estimated as sunny and actual rainfall is 0. The estimation is considered wrong, otherwise.

return

1. int. Number of days as rainy
2. int. Number of days where the estimation is correct

small example of data:

```
15.5,32,51,0
18.4,30.5,57,1.2
20.9,25.7,52,0
17.1,25.8,82,5.8
16.4,27,82,3
10,19.7,62,11.6
8.8,21.9,78,0
8.4,25.3,78,0
```

```
def estimate_weather(filename):
    rain = 0
    sun = 0 
    sunny_correct = 0
    rainy_correct = 0
    correct = 0
    with open(filename, 'r') as handle:
        for temp in handle:
            if temp.strip():
                temperature = list(map(float, temp.strip().split(',')))
                if (temperature[1] - temperature[0]) > 10 and temperature[2] > 50:
                    rain = rain + 1
                else: 
                    sun = sun + 1
            if (temperature[1] - temperature[0]) > 10 and temperature[2] > 50 and temperature[3] > 0:
                rainy_correct = correct + 1
            if (temperature[1] - temperature[0]) <= 10 and temperature[2] <= 50 and temperature[3] ==  0:
                sunny_correct = sunny_correct + 1
        correct = rainy_correct + sunny_correct

    return rainy, correct
```

i am getting string index out of range. any suggestions?

Comment: your sample data shows not commas, but you split on a comma: `temp.strip().split(',')`

Comment: @richard oh sorry there should be commas, ill edit it

Comment: I cannot duplicate your "index out of range" but (0,0) is not the answer. [https://onlinegdb.com/60c6YaQdT](https://onlinegdb.com/60c6YaQdT). is the expected answer (5,3)?

Comment: @richard i just edited my code to fix the conditions. I had >= instead of <= on the sunny_correct part! So I believe the answer should be (5,2). --- wait i think you are correct and the answer is (5,3) my bad.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... The estimation is considered correct if estimated as rainy and actual rainfall is greater than 0. also it is correct if estimated as sunny and actual rainfall is 0. The estimation is considered wrong, otherwise. ..."*

You haven't provided information regarding which value represents what—i.e., estimated, versus actual.
I've adapted the following to your code.

And, as a note, you are assigning *rainy_correct* the results of *correct + 1*.
I believe you instead mean,

```java
rainy_correct += 1
correct += 1
```

And, that would mean *sunny_correct = sunny_correct + 1* may be a typo.

```java
sunny_correct += 1
correct += 1
```

Consider the following.

```py
s = [[15.5, 32, 51, 0],
     [18.4, 30.5, 57, 1.2],
     [20.9, 25.7, 52, 0],
     [17.1, 25.8, 82, 5.8],
     [16.4, 27, 82, 3],
     [10, 19.7, 62, 11.6],
     [8.8, 21.9, 78, 0],
     [8.4, 25.3, 78, 0]]
rain = 0
sun = 0
sunny_correct = 0
rainy_correct = 0
correct = 0
for x in s:
    if x[1] - x[0] > 10 and x[2] > 50:
        rain += 1
        if x[3] > 0:
            rainy_correct += 1
            correct += 1
    else: sun += 1
    if x[1] - x[0] <= 10 and x[2] <= 50 and x[3] == 0:
        sunny_correct += 1
        correct += 1
correct = rainy_correct + sunny_correct

print(f'{rain=}', f'{correct=}')
```

Output

```
rain=5 correct=2
```

Answer (score 0):

## use the CSV module

Or use pandas.
Doing "import [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)"
would improve clarity of your code.

## tuple unpack

The `[0]` .. `[3]` [magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))
indexes are cryptic and unhelpful.
Prefer to unpack with:

```
            lo, hi, humid, precip = ... .split...
```

---

## bug

Given that "rainy" ≡ "not sunny",
we seem to have defined twice as many
local variables as necessary.

```
                if temp[0] - temp[1] > 10 and temp[2] > 50:
```

Here you are asking about `lo - hi`.

It appears you meant `hi - lo`, or perhaps `abs( ... )` value.

The `elif` clause then winds up having surprising consequences,
different from Author's Intent.

Write a [test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
for this already.
Then obvious logic errors would be immediately apparent.

## descriptive variable names

The throwaway name `temp`, for "temporary", is not helpful,
especially when you want to communicate details to collaborators.

Plus, in a weather context it evokes the notion of "temperature".

## vague problem statement

> i am getting string index out of range.

I can't see your traceback, so it's unclear what happened.
Please edit the question to include relevant technical details.

EDIT

```
        for temp in file_handle:
            if temp.strip():
                temp = list(...]
                if temp[0] - temp[1] ...
            elif temp[0] - temp[1] ...
```

Oh, now I see.
zomg, that's so messed up!
You gave `temp` the meaning of "here is a str line of text from the file",
and then you changed it to "here is a list of parsed values",
and then you went back to "here is that original str".

You're not making the code easy to read.

Invent descriptive names for these concepts, please.

De-referencing element `[1]` of the `str` when you
intended "give me the daily high" is not going to go well,
and similarly for the other magic indexes.

## summary

Ya know, they call it "code" for a reason.

But here's the thing.
You don't *have* to write cryptic code.
You can make it descriptive so it reads
like a novel or a sonnet.
Think of the poor reader when you're writing.

And write some unit tests already.
They don't take any longer than interactive testing,
and you get to keep them forever.
They will helpfully pinpoint bugs, if you write bugs.

Comment: you are correct about my hi - lo issue thanks! I still do not understand what to do about the out of range index error

Comment: omg thank you! I fixed it and was able to run my code! I got the rainy output right, but my correct output is not. I edited my code once again, if you have suggestions.

Comment: Here's my suggestion: Include the [unit test(s)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) for your revised code, in the question. Show us how you're invoking the target code, and what results you get. If the act of writing a test encourages you to break out a Helper function, well, so much the better! (Here's a hint: Write at least one helper. It should accept `(lo, hi, humid, precip)` and return some interesting result(s), perhaps as a tuple. It might be convenient to make it a method so it can update a `self.correct` counter.)

Answer (score 0):

I got (5, 3) with your sample data. I think you are doing more comparisons than needed?  uncomment the comments to validate the data.
https://onlinegdb.com/jSzYYPHo7d

```py
def estimate_weather(filename):
    rainy, correct = 0, 0
    with open(filename, 'r') as file_handle:
        for temp in file_handle:
            temp = list(map(float, temp.strip().split(',')))
            # diff = temp[1] - temp[0]
            if (temp[1] - temp[0]) > 10 and temp[2] > 50:
                # print('rain', temp, diff)
                rainy += 1
                if temp[3] > 0: correct += 1
            else:
                # print(' sun', temp, diff)
                if temp[3] <= 0: correct += 1
    
    return rainy, correct

print(estimate_weather('file.csv'))
```